# Apache Mahout Database to Sequence File

Tags: hadoop, classification, mahout

I am currently trying to play around with mahout. I purchased the book Mahout in Action.
The whole process is understood and with simple test data sets I was already successful.

Now I have a classification problem that I would like to solve.

the target variable is found, which I call - for now - x.
The existing data in our database has already been classified with -1, 0 and +1.

We defined several predictor variables which we select with an SQL query.

These are the product's attributes: language, country, category (of the shop), title, description.

Now I want them to directly be written in a SequenceFile, for which I wrote a little helper class that will append to the sequence file each time a new row of the SQL resultset has been processed:

```
public void appendToFile(String classification, String databaseID, String language, String country, String vertical, String title, String description) {
    int count = 0;
    Text key = new Text();
    Text value = new Text();

    key.set("/" + classification + "/" + databaseID);
    //??value.set(message);
    try {
        this.writer.append(key, value);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If I only had the title or so, I could simply store it in the value - but how do I store mutiple values like country, lang, and so on, in that particular key?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

you shouldnt be storing structures in a seq file, just dump all the text you have seperated by a space,

it's simply a place to put all your content for term counting and such when using something like Naive Bayes, it cares not about structure.

Then when you have classification, lookup the structure in your database.